# change bootstrap button text before rendering d3 svg object

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, svg, d3.js

I've got code aimed at visualizing some complex data.  The user first selects a data file to load; after clicking the load button, the page generates a "plot" button with an onclick event handler with the function `renderPlots()`.

When the user clicks the "plot" button, then all the plots are properly generated and I'm happy.  However, in the case of a larger data set, the plotting process may take a few seconds so I'd like to change the button text to something like "rendering..." while the plots are being generated so that the user knows their plots are on the way.

As per the bootstrap documentation for dynamically changing button text, I've tried something like

```
function renderPlots() {
    $("#render").button("loading");

    rest of code that does all the D3 plot generating...;

    $("#render").button("reset");
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it doesn't actually change the button text first, it's doing things asynchronously and I'm at a loss of how I can force the button text to change on screen before any plotting actually starts.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if I understood the issue, stuff is running synchronously — **not a**synchronously — which is why the browser doesn't get a chance to refresh the DOM with the new button text prior to starting the big processing task. If you were to `console.log` the button text somewhere between the two calls to `.button()` you'd see that the text is set to `"loading"`; it just doesn't appear yet.

If so, then using `setTimeout` to delay the start of processing until the next "frame" will fix the issue:

```
function renderPlots() {
  $("#render").button("loading");
  setTimeout(function() {
    // rest of code that does all the D3 plot generating...;
    $("#render").button("reset");
  }, 100); // even 0 will do the trick
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it (again) :), here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cXoAeZavclJI1wprZrA?p=preview) I was coding up.

Comment: No troubles, your answers are always spot on.